# How does pressure inside a tire works?

Tags: pressure, popular-science

Why do we have to inflate our tires to a set psi every once in a while?

When we drive, does the tire loses air? Is it because of the difference in pressure?

Would a properly installed new tire lose pressure over time? Or do we have to pump air due to poor installation?

Comment: Everything loses pressure over time. ‘Hermetically sealed’ systems are allowed to have real, measurable leak rates.

Comment: Actually the biggest source of leakage in most car tires is because people          check the pressure regularly, and each check releases some air. I've had car tires that stayed at their original pressure for two or three years, simply by leaving them alone rather than fussing about checking them every few days..

Answer (score 3):

All tires lose air over time via [permeation](https://talkcarswell.com/why-do-tires-lose-air/), which is the diffusion of air outward through the rubber.  This is typically responsible for a pressure loss of ~1-3 psi per month, according to the linked article.

Of course, if your tire was not installed properly or if it has been physically damaged, the pressure will decrease faster.  It's also worth noting that your tire pressure also depends on the weather, decreasing when it's cold and increasing when it's hot.

Answer (score -2):

> Why do we have to inflate our tires to a set psi every once in a while?

Inflating our tyres of cars turn the shape of tyres to more cylendrical. So because of this you will not get any anti torque by the normal force that would oppose your torque provided by the engine. That is why you might have seen that it is difficult to drive with a flat tyre.

> As we drive the tire loses air? It's because of the difference in pressure?

As we drive the tyres heat up and thus increasing the pressure and further increasing the pressure difference.

Yeah as the pressure difference arise gases have a tendency to leak and will obviously leak even as you can never turn it completely leak proof as air can even diffuse.

> A proper installed new tire, will lose pressure over time? or we have to pump air due to poor installation?

A proper installed tyre will lose air but obviously after a long durtion rather than a worn out tyre. This is because of the thinning of the rubber tyre surface or due to the punctures that you got repaired(as isaid before air would leak)